# Reading json in javascript from a get request

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I have been trying to read data from my json output sent from a flask json dump via javascript.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: m_url+"bank_trans/get_banks/",
credentials: 'include', 
headers: {
    'AccessToken': acc,
},
success:function(data) {
  console.log(data)

  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     console.log(
         data.total_amount + "<br />"
     );
  }


}

});
```

The output of the json dump, from console.log:

```
[{"total_amount": 1254275355.95, "BANK_NAME": "FIRST BANK"}, {"total_amount": 49307548.55, "BANK_NAME": "GT BANK"}, {"total_amount": 100000.00, "BANK_NAME": "STANBIC IBTC BANK"}, {"total_amount": 79100000.00, "BANK_NAME": "STERLING BANK"}, {"total_amount": 50133150.68, "BANK_NAME": "UBA"}, {"total_amount": 13000000.00, "BANK_NAME": "ZENITH BANK"}]
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: @azro thanks, data.length gives 349 and the for loop doesn't work as expected i dont know what different have worked with something like this in a previous project which works, this doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now `data` is a JSON content : a string, you need to load it as a JS structure, here a list of objects

#### Simple solution

Parse the JSON, and also use `data[i].total_amount` and not `data.total_amount`

```js
let data = '[{"total_amount": 1254275355.95, "BANK_NAME": "FIRST BANK"}, {"total_amount": 49307548.55, "BANK_NAME": "GT BANK"}, {"total_amount": 100000.00, "BANK_NAME": "STANBIC IBTC BANK"}, {"total_amount": 79100000.00, "BANK_NAME": "STERLING BANK"}, {"total_amount": 50133150.68, "BANK_NAME": "UBA"}, {"total_amount": 13000000.00, "BANK_NAME": "ZENITH BANK"}]'
data = JSON.parse(data)
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    console.log(data[i].total_amount);
}
```

---

#### Better solution

Regarding [`jquery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Use `dataType: "json"` to load automatically from JSON

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: m_url + "bank_trans/get_banks/",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'AccessToken': acc,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        for (i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            console.log(data[i].total_amount);
        }
    }
});
```